# Yahoo Finance URL not working (again since 05/2018)

Tags: java

Thanks to this valuable site, I found useful tips since 08/2017 to retrieve cookies and crumbs for ***Yahoo Finance*** site in order to solve my bulk quote download problem.

Nevertheless my program (written in Java) doesn't work anymore since end of May 2018.
I get the following error message :

> CookieHandler retrieved cookie:
>   GUCS="AX62rEgH";$Path="/";$Domain=".yahoo.com" Added cookie using
>   cookie handler getContent on quote failed: java.io.IOException: Server
>   returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL:
>   https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/AC.PA?period1=1526594400&period2=1527631200&interval=1d&events=history&crumb=null

I think that the crumb search is failing..

FYI : I am a Java programmer "amateur" since 2003

Please advise if anybody knows how to solve this problem

Comment: HTTP 401 is unauthorized. Get authorized. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401

Comment: I don't know what you're actually asking here, unfortunately. If you had code that doesn't work, you're going to have to show [mcve]. If it's a general question along the lines of "what does this error mean?" then that feels like it falls under the ["first search and research"](/help/how-to-ask) requirement on your part before posting a question.

Comment: Thanks to Maxzoom and Dave for their prompt anwer .

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Maxzoom and Dave for their prompt answer. I apologize for the lack of details in my question.For that reason I am adding the complete java method I was using successfully until last month, thanks on one hand to the code of Serge dated Aug 27 2017
Since the method is too long in the comment page I will paste in a new answer Here is the method below:

```
public static String getQuote3(String quoteString, String stock) throws IOException {
    int         curByte;
    char        curChar;
    String      curQuote,z;
    boolean     priceFlag;

    z="rr";
    //////////////Search for cookies

    try {
        CookieManager manager = new CookieManager();
        manager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
        CookieHandler.setDefault(manager);
        URL quoteURL = new URL("https://fr.finance.yahoo.com/quote"+stock+"/history?p="+stock);

        URLConnection con = quoteURL.openConnection();
        con.getContent();
        // get cookies from underlying CookieStore
        CookieStore cookieJar = manager.getCookieStore();
        java.util.List <HttpCookie> cookies = cookieJar.getCookies();
        for (HttpCookie cookie: cookies) {
            System.out.println("CookieHandler retrieved cookie: " + cookie);
        }

        //now you can search for the crumb in the yahoo site:
        String crumb = null;
        InputStream inStream = con.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader irdr = new InputStreamReader(inStream);
        BufferedReader rsv = new BufferedReader(irdr);
        Pattern crumbPattern = Pattern.compile(".*\"CrumbStore\":\\{\"crum\":\"([^\"]+)\"\\}.*");

        String line = null;
        while (crumb == null && (line = rsv.readLine()) != null) {
            Matcher matcher = crumbPattern.matcher(line);
            if (matcher.matches() && matcher.group(1).length()< 12)
            crumb = matcher.group(1);
            if(crumb!= null)
            {
                System.out.println ("crumb= " + crumb) ;
            }
        }
        rsv.close();
        String quoteUrls = quoteString + crumb;

        // create cookie
        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("UserName", "John Doe");

        // add cookie to CookieStore for a particular URL quoteURL = new URL(quoteUrls);

        try {
            cookieJar.add(quoteURL.toURI(), cookie);
            System.out.println("Added cookie using cookie handler");
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to set cookie using CookieHandler");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        con.connect();

        try {
            DataInputStream quoteStream = new DataInputStream(quoteURL.openStream());
            priceFlag = false;
            curQuote = "";
            while( (curByte = quoteStream.read()) != -1) {
                curChar = (char) curByte;

                curQuote += curChar;
            }
            System.out.println(curQuote);
            priceFlagn = true;

            return curQuote;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("getContent on quote failed: " + e);
            priceFlagn = false;
        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        System.err.println("Yikes. URL exception");
    }

    return z;
}
```